# bonfire error 500 when sending data to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I keep getting this error for a bonfire application that I am trying to learn for the first time. I primarily know Codeigniter and bonfire is derived from it so I should be able to do anything I can do in CI here in bonfire.

I am trying to send data from a view to a controller via HTML Forms and this keeps showing up. I am going nuts with this error, I cannot even trace what's giving it out.

```
An Error Was Encountered

The action you have requested is not allowed. You either do not have access, or your login 
session has expired and you need to sign in again.
```

Can somebody who knows how to use bonfire help me? It seems to have a pretty bad documentation as of this posting.

Comment: Can u please post the code you believe to be causing the errors

Comment: A bit late, but you need a CSRF token https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523011/codeigniter-csrf-token