# CodeIgniter , Csrf token

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Have Trouble

View

```
<form method="post" action="test/csrf">
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();?>" value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash();?>">
```

Controller

```
echo $this->input->post($this->security->get_csrf_token_name());
```

I Can't Show Token Code

Comment: Where you can't show token code? view or controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Access the Csrf Token in controller**

In controller u can get name and value of csrf as follow

```
        echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); // for the name
        echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash();  // for the value
```

**Enable CSRF in Config file**

```
 $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
 $config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
 $config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
```

**1. Used CSRF Tokens using form helper**

We have two way to add CSRF tokens; if we are thinking to update your form with CodeIgniter form helper class then CSRF tokens will automatic added or if you are thinking to adjust in custom form then we need to add custom hidden input name and its value.

When we will use form helper class:

```
  <?php echo form_open(base_url( 'user/login' ), array( 'id' => 'login', 'class' => 'login' ));?>
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <input type="password" name="password" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Using form helper class will automatically added input filed into the form with a random token value to prevent CSRF.

**2. When we use custom form:**

We need to add a input filed to prevent our custom form with CSRF.

```
    $csrf = array(
    'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
    'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
    );

     <input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />
```

If you use the form helper, then form_open() will automatically insert a hidden csrf field in your forms. If not,

Then you can use `get_csrf_token_name()` and `get_csrf_hash()`

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html

http://www.sks.com.np/secure-your-codeigniter-application-using-csrf-token/

Comment: if u r using form helper there is no requirement of setting custom token the form helper automatically generates token