# Sent AJAX form value with CSRF variable in Code Igniter

Tags: php, jquery, csrf

I'd like to make an AJAX post to save my data into database. The problem is I cannot send my form value together with the csrf variable.

My current script:

```
var form_val    = $("#form").serializeArray();

    form_val.push({name: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>', value: csrfHash});
                
    $.ajax({
        url         : url,          
        type        : 'POST',
        dataType    : 'JSON',           
        data        : { data:form_val }
    })
    .done(function(data){

        //SUCCESS  
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data){

        //FAIL
    });
```

But, if I change my script into this, the csrf probelm is solved but no data is saved to database

```
var form_val    = $("#form").serializeArray();
            
$.ajax({
    url         : url,          
    type        : 'POST',
    dataType    : 'JSON',           
    data        : { data:form_val, "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" : csrfHash }
})
.done(function(data){

    //SUCCESS  
})
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data){

    //FAIL
});
```

HTML for idden input:

```
<?php
    
    $token_name = $this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
    $token_hash = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
    
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='csrf_name' name='".$token_name."' value='".$token_name."' />";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='csrf_hash' name='".$token_hash."' value='".$token_hash."' />";
?>
```

Comment: simply create a hidden input into the form and send the data along with the form.

Comment: @OnkarSingh I've done it. But still no luck. Perhap I miss something

Comment: Show the HTML and hidden input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523011/codeigniter-csrf-token

Comment: Hi, does your problem got solved ?

Comment: @Swati not yet.

Comment: @OnkarSingh Did I miss something in my code?

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6s583exr/) should work .

Comment: @Swati I still get `Forbidden` error

Comment: how does your data should look alike ?

Comment: @Swati my current script should work because I sent form value and csrf together. But, I got `Forbidden` error. What am I missing?

Comment: when you submit your form without ajax does that work ?   Because `403` error comes when server doesn't accept the request or authorize it . I am not sure where might be  problem . But, check at your server what it accept .

Comment: @Swati if I ignore the csrf completely everything is fine